# AngularJS pushing/updating new data (likes/dislikes) to API using PUT

Tags: angularjs, api, put

I am trying to create an app that counts likes for beer! This would updates the API the beers are stored on and in turn update the number of likes on the API and angularJS view using the PUT method. I am able to get the view to work correctly increasing every time the like is clicked. I am unsure why my PUT method continues to return a 404 and will not update the API. please see code below for my put method. I have also included my JS and HTML for this. I feel like I am close but cannot figure out how to get the "likes" to update on the API. Thank you in advance!! I think i am passing incorrect data to the PUT method.

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="beerApp" ng-controller="BeerController" class="jumbotron">
    <div class="all-beer">
        <div class="single-beer" ng-repeat="beer in allBeer">
            <div>{{beer.name}}</div>
            <div>{{beer.likes}}</div>
            <button ng-click="decrease(beer)">X</button>
            <button ng-click="increase(beer)">\3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
 angular.module('beerApp', []).controller('BeerController', function($scope, $http) {

             $scope.allBeer = [];
             $scope.beerSum = function() {
             $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: /api/beers
              }).
             then( function(response) {

             if(typeof response === 'object') {
                var dataArr = response.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
                    var beer = dataArr[i];

                    $scope.allBeer.push(beer);
                }

            } else {
                return;
            }

            }, function(error) {
            console.log('i am an error', error);
            })
          };

          $scope.beerSum();

          $scope.increase = function(beer){

          var newLikes = beer.likes++;

          $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/beer/',
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.allBeer.likes),
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Updated!");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("not updated")

        });

    };
```

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: You have forgotten to close your ' in put methods url

Comment: Also you are sending the wrong data I believe to your server. You are saying update the likes, but you aren't saying which beer's likes to increase. Also you are stringfying a property that I don't see.

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub I see that your profile says web dev intern. One summer ago I was a web dev intern for a company that wanted me to learn AngularJs. As a previous intern to a current one, if the version of Angular isn't a requirement I highly recommend moving to Angular 4. There are many reasons for this but the major one is the coding tools are more supportive and will tell you about errors you may be making early. Visual Studio Code and Angular 4 go very well together and there are plenty of guides online. Please contact me if you need any help getting started, I'd be glad to talk to you.

Comment: well thank you so much!!! I really think if i can get the PUT code working to push the updated likes to the API (did not include link on code above but that is not the issue) then i can complete what i need this app for. The last piece was getting the new likes and eventually adding new beers to the API.

Comment: Also with the updating which beers likes. Each beer will have a picture and 2 buttons and you should be able to like and dislike each beer, so wouldnt the binding choose which beers likes to increased based on which button you were clicking on??? this was my understanding anyway, and this works in the view but the data isnt saved once you refresh the page, which is why i am trying to push the update to the API whenever the like or dislike is clicked. Does this make sense?

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub Your idea is correct for pushing to an API to persist the information and I understand what you are trying to do, I would write one method called updateLikes, that accepts a beer object, and a number. Then your dislike button would do `updateLikes(beer, -1)` and vice versa `updateLikes(beer, 1)`. I have to say though that directly changing the likes should occur on the server only for security reasons but for a simple app this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first you are missing some syntax for the http api's. Secondly you are calling a property on an array that doesn't exist. Thirdly your api won't work because of the logic that you have. You have an array of beers and you want to increase the likes on a single beer. Create a method on the server that accepts a beer, the server will take that beer and increase it's likes by 1, then save to the database or whatever.

Depending on the server you are using you have two options.
You can define a command simply at `/api/beers` and configure the server to accept an object and use that objects id for the server update. If this is the case I recommend creating this endpoint, `/api/beers/update` and make it a POST, and pass it the object, then within this command do all your update logic.

Or for example the Microsoft Web Api the default put (update) endpoint looks like so, `public void Update(int id, object data){}` with a url of `/api/beers/{id}`. To use this method you need to change the code for the `updateLikes` method I wrote. 
See Below:

```
$scope.updateLikes = function(beer, likeCount){
        beer.likes+= likeCount;
        $http({
              method: 'PUT',
              url: '/api/beer/' + beer.id,
              data: JSON.stringify(beer),
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log("Updated!");
                //Trigger reload of data
                $scope.beerSum();
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("not updated")
            });
    };
```

### Extra Help

If you are still having trouble and are working in a GitHub environment I would gladly help you with your code more directly. Other than that the answer I have posted answer's your question, and does so in what I believe to be good coding practices for AngularJS. With one minor exception there code be a changes to the line that reads, `beer.likes += likeCount` because this also updates the original beer object. I suppose that is preference, but please contact me if you need more help.

#### JS:

```
     angular.module('beerApp', []).controller('BeerController', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.allBeer = [];
     $scope.beerSum = function() {
     $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/beers' //<-- Added string opening and closing tags
      }).
     then( function(response) {

         if(typeof response === 'object') {
            var dataArr = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
                var beer = dataArr[i];

                $scope.allBeer.push(beer);
            }

        } else {
            return;
        }

        }, function(error) {
        console.log('i am an error', error);
        })
      };

      $scope.beerSum();

      $scope.increase = function(beer){

      var newLikes = beer.likes++;

//Your code
          $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/beer/', //<-- closing 
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.allBeer.likes), //<-- Where does likes come from? $scope.allBeer is an array of beer but the array itself doesn't have a property called likes.
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Updated!");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("not updated")

        });

//End your code

//My Code
    beer.likes+=1; //<-- My bad I fixed this.
    $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          url: '/api/beer/', //<-- closing 
          data: JSON.stringify(beer), //<-- The object you passed into the function
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Updated!");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("not updated")

        });
//End my code

    };
```

### Possible problems

1. Your api doesn't work with put, in which case this question isn't the correct one.

   2. Something else is internally wrong with your program, but from this point on I think you're looking at something wrong with your api, whatever that may be.

```js
angular.module('beerApp', []).controller('BeerController', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.allBeer = [];
     $scope.beerSum = function() {
       $scope.allBeer.push({
         "name": "Miller Lite",
         "likes": 0
       });
     $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/beers' //<-- Added string opening and closing tags
      }).
     then( function(response) {
         if(typeof response === 'object') {
            var dataArr = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
                var beer = dataArr[i];

                $scope.allBeer.push(beer);
            }
          }
        }, function(error) {
        console.log('i am an error', error);
        })
      };

      $scope.beerSum();

      $scope.updateLikes = function(beer, likeCount){
        beer.likes+= likeCount;
        $http({
              method: 'PUT',
              url: '/api/beer/',
              data: JSON.stringify(beer),
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log("Updated!");
                //Trigger reload of data
                $scope.beerSum();
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("not updated")
            });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="beerApp" ng-controller="BeerController" class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Beers on Tap</h1>
      <div class="all-beer">
        <div class="single-beer" ng-repeat="beer in allBeer">
          <div>{{beer.name}}</div>
          <div>{{beer.likes}}</div>
          <button ng-click="updateLikes(beer, -1)">Down Vote</button>
          <button ng-click="updateLikes(beer, 1)">Up Vote</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: He is pushing beer objects to $scope.allBeer after get method. So maybe each beer object may contain likes. BTW when you give an answer please provide an explanation as to why the answer solves the question. :)

Comment: Each beer may contain a like but the overall array doesn't have a property of `likes`.

Comment: Yes you are right, he forgot to put the index to reference the array

Comment: But if you look that he passed the beer he means to increase into the function for better coding practice once he enters the method he should use params that have been given to that function.

Comment: I didnt use the API in my code snippet here, but the API stores Objects containing the Beer name, id and likes.

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub then my code example will work for you. It takes the object you passed into the function increases it's likes by 1 and then you send that to the server.

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub something worth noting is that once your update request completes you should probably do an update on all beers, which you have a function for.

Comment: Is this update going to be another PUT? but a similar function to what I used under the GET for allbeers??

Comment: @BaileyMiller I am getting an error in the console saying PUT then my API string, then 404 not found. I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: @BaileyMiller I believe I have to define the index of the beer I am looking to update to use PUT. I believe this should be done with a for loop. This is as close as I have gotten to getting this right for now.

Comment: Look at answer for possible ways that different API's handle PUT commands

Comment: @BaileyMiller figured this out! Thank you so much! I do believe I have a better understanding of this concept now! Much appreciated

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub Here is a GitHub repo I am starting that I have some spare time and I will develop an Angular 4 version of this idea. Link: https://github.com/BaileyMillerSSI/ngxBeerTap